# Can nth-child be used with this HTML structure?

Tags: html, css

I have a [simplified HTML structure](http://jsfiddle.net/LbCf6/) like so:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="box-header"></div>
        <div class="box-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="box-header"></div>
        <div class="box-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="box-header"></div>
        <div class="box-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="box-header"></div>
        <div class="box-content"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="box-header"></div>
        <div class="box-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="box-header"></div>
        <div class="box-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to be able to target the `.box-header` div's using the `nth-child` CSS psuedo-selector. However, the following CSS:

```
#container .box-header:nth-child(3) { background-color: red; }
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Can `nth-child` be used with this HTML structure?

Please see this jsFiddle for reference: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LbCf6/)

Comment: Do you want to target the box-header of the third item or all box-header elements?

Comment: Neither, I wanted to be able to use `nth-child` so I can 'set and forget' the `.box-header` colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `nth-child` with class `item` and assign to its `box-header` a style

try this:

```
#container .item:nth-child(3) .box-header{ background-color: red; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LbCf6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.item .box-header:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: This would not work since then all box-headers would be the same color.

Answer (score 0):

## container .item:nth-child(n) > .box-header{ background-color: red; }